# Confusion about the proper way to read child nodes with XmlReader

Tags: c#, xml, xmlreader

Let's suppose i have the following Xml:

```
<Sections>
   <Section>
      <Item>
         <Field> myfield </Field>
         <Field> myfield </Field>
      </Item>
      <Item>
         <Field> myfield </Field>
         <Field> myfield </Field>
      </Item>
   </Section>
   <Section>
      <Item>
         <Field> myfield </Field>
         <Field> myfield </Field>
      </Item>
   </Section>
</Sections>
```

Now what i want is to loop though Sections, and work on each item separately, so i was thinking to do something like the following:

```
reader.ReadToDescendant("Section")
do
{
    Console.WriteLine("Section");
    reader.ReadToDescendant("Item");
    do
    {
        var element = (XElement)XNode.ReadFrom(reader);
        foreach (XElement el in element.Elements())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(el.Value);
        }
    }while(reader.ReadToNextSibling("Item"));
}while (reader.ReadToNextSibling("Section"))
```

My question is. If i repeat the same do-while loop for Item nodes, does the reader stop when it finds the closing Section tag or it will search in all the xml? Should i use reader.ReadSubtree() before the inner loop?

Note that i'm not looking for standard answer like "Use XDocument". I know that dom are easier to use, but they are not suitable for my situation

Comment: Sounds like something you can easily test yourself

Comment: Frankly, the only good answer I can give here is: "carefully". I work with serialization APIs *all the time*, and `XmlReader` is *far and away* the most awkward one to work with - figuring out which operations advance the reader to where is often a case of trial and `Exception`.

Comment: @MarcGravell that's why i was asking. I honestly find the documentation on msdn about XmlReader method pretty frustrating, and it's not easy for me to figure out which method is more suitable and when. I was looking for someone more experienced then me to clarify something

Comment: @DanieleSartori well, based on years of working with those APIs, I can clarify exactly two things: 1) you're not wrong - the documentation is unclear, and 2) the API is awkward to use

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `ReadSubtree` to create inner reader to work with current node. Without this, the reader will not stop and continue the search until the end of the document.

```
reader.ReadToDescendant("Section");
do
{
    Console.WriteLine("Section");
    using (var innerReader = reader.ReadSubtree())
    {
        while (innerReader.ReadToFollowing("Field"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("field");
        }
    }
} while (reader.ReadToNextSibling("Section"));
```

Comment: Check my edit. I added the code for the inner loop. From my test, it seems that it gives the same output. In which case it is better to use theReadSubtree?

Comment: @DanieleSartori - `XElement` will read all `Item` content in memory. If it is large, then memory may not be enough. Then you need to go to inner xmlreader.